# How to add column to table in python script?

Tags: python, sql, csv, sqlite

I need to add an extra column at the end of a table.

I have a python script that a (now missing) developer made for me but I'm not being able to add a column and add data with success.

Can someone help me out, by telling me where exactly is necessary to change?

I've tried adding on the schemas `, piNew text` after `piLongitude real`but when I run it data is not loaded to PI table. PlacesCovered table is loaded OK.

Thanks a lot!

Here goes the main code:

```
import codecs
import csv
import sys
import sqlite3
import random, string
import os
import StringIO

schemas = {
    'PI':'id integer primary key, piCountry text, piCity text, piType integer, piLatitude real, piLongitude real',
    'PlacesCovered':'id integer primary key, pcCountry text, pcCity text, pcName text, pcType text, pcLatitude real, pcLongitude real'}

def main():
    if os.path.isfile(DATABASE_NAME):
        os.remove(DATABASE_NAME)
    db = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_NAME)
    c = db.cursor()

    if TEST_DATA:
        for name, schema in schemas.items():
            make_table(c,name,schema)
        add_test_data(c,'PI',TEST_DATA_PI_COUNT,False)
        add_test_data(c,'PlacesCovered',5000,True)
    else:
        for name, schema in schemas.items():
            make_table(c,name,schema)
            add_data(c,name)
    c.execute('create index sort on PlacesCovered(pcCountry,pcType,pcName)');

    db.commit()
    os.system('open '+PROJECT_PATH)
    print('Data imported! Now build and run the app in Xcode.\n')


def make_table(c,name,schema):
    c.execute('drop table if exists %s_rtree'%(name))
    c.execute('create virtual table %s_rtree using rtree(id,minX,maxX,minY,maxY)'%(name))
    c.execute('drop table if exists %s'%(name))
    c.execute('create table %s(%s)'%(name,schema))

def make_bounds(lat, lon):
    return [lon,lon,lat,lat]

def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                            dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')

def add_data(c, name):
    encodings = ["utf-8","iso-8859-1"]
    # encodings = ["utf-8"]
    # with codecs.open('%s.csv'%(name), "r", "iso-8859-1") as infile:
    # normalize newlines

    text = None
    print("Loading %s.csv..."%(name))
    for idx,encoding in enumerate(encodings):
        try:
            infile = codecs.open('%s.csv'%(name), "r", encoding)
            text = infile.read()
            break
        except IOError as e:
            print(e)
            break
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            if idx == len(encodings)-1:
                print("Incompatible character encoding.")
                print("Please export your CSVs as UTF-8 or Latin 1 (ISO-8859-1).")
            continue
    if text is None:
        print("Couldn't read %s.csv"%(name))
        sys.exit(0)
    text = '\n'.join(text.splitlines())

    id = 1
    sql = u'insert into %s values'%(name)
    reader = unicode_csv_reader(StringIO.StringIO(text))
    for row in reader:
        if row is None or len(row) < 2:
            continue
        placeholders = ','.join(['?' for field in row])
        bounds = make_bounds(row[-2],row[-1]);
        c.execute(u'insert into %s values(?, %s)'%(name,placeholders),[id]+row)
        c.execute(u'insert into %s_rtree values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'%(name),[id]+bounds)
        id += 1

def word(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for i in range(length))

def random_coord(coord):
    lat = coord[0] + (random.random()-0.5)*TEST_DATA_RANGE
    lon = coord[1] + (random.random()-0.5)*TEST_DATA_RANGE
    return [lat,lon]

def add_test_data(c, name, rows, include_name):
    id = 1
    sql = 'insert into %s values'%(name)
    for i in range(rows):
        coord = random_coord(TEST_DATA_CENTROID)
        row = [word(5),word(5)]
        if (include_name):
            row = row + [word(5)]
        row = row + [random.randint(1,2)] 
        row = row + coord
        # row = ['Country','City','Name','Type','Lat','Lon']
        placeholders = ','.join(['?' for field in row])
        bounds = make_bounds(row[-2],row[-1]);
        c.execute('insert into %s values(?, %s)'%(name,placeholders),[id]+row)
        c.execute('insert into %s_rtree values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'%(name),[id]+bounds)
        id += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Print all `c.execute` arguments to see if they are correct.

Comment: How do you mean to derive the value for the piNew field?  Should it be in your input csv?  Do you calculate it based upon some other runtime data?  My bet is that your inputs don't have an additional column, so you are silently failing on each insert to PI because you aren't providing enough values to satisfy all the required fields in the table.  Does the PI_rtree table get created and populated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it just worked by adding the column not at the end of the table, but before of the coordinates fields.

I do not have an explanation, but tried and worked without having to change anything else on the script.